# Xamarin Forms not Debugging and ZXing freezing all the application

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, zxing

I made an application to read some QR Codes using Zxing on Xamarin. Days before yesterday, it was working good, but since yesterday I have this problem:

I put a breakpoint in OnAppearing() method, but it's ignored, Ok... When I click in the Zxing button, to open the scanner, the application stops, but don't show nothing, only freeze, no errors, no messages, no debug, nothing. My code is the same as when it was working, nothing changed. If anybody could help me, I'll be grateful.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = this;

        this.IsBusy = false;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var dados = new AcessoDB();

        if (dados.GetAlunos().Count() > 0)
        {
            var infopage = new Wallet();
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(infopage, Navigation.NavigationStack[0]);
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            codeqr.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private async void Scan_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
        string img;
        this.IsBusy = true;


        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var scan = new ZXingScannerPage();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(scan);
            scan.OnScanResult += async (result) =>
            {
                bool liberado = await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(-1);
                if (!liberado)
                {
                    return;
                }
                scan.IsScanning = false;
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                    {
                        var parseResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result);

                        if (parseResult != null)
                        {
                            var hash = sha256_hash(result.ToString());
                            Aluno items = new Aluno();
                            try
                            {
                                scan.IsAnalyzing = false;
                                scan.IsScanning = false;
                                items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Aluno>(result.ToString());
                                img = GetImage(items.Foto);
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                scan.IsScanning = false;
                                scan.IsAnalyzing = false;
                                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                                await DisplayAlert("Ops...", "Ocorreu algum erro com a leitura do seu código, tente de novo.", "Ok!");
                                return;
                            }
                            var info = new Aluno
                            {
                                Matricula = items.Matricula,
                                Nome = items.Nome,
                                RG = items.RG,
                                Nascimento = items.Nascimento,
                                Curso = items.Curso,
                                Campus = items.Campus,
                                Periodos = items.Periodos,
                                Modalidade = items.Modalidade,
                                Validade = items.Validade,
                                Hash = hash,
                                Foto = img
                            };

                            var infopage = new Wallet();
                            var dados = new AcessoDB();

                            if (!await dados.InserirAlunoAsync(info))
                            {
                                scan.IsAnalyzing = false;
                                scan.IsScanning = false;
                                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                                await DisplayAlert("Ops...", "Esse código não consta no nosso banco de dados, tem certeza que estuda no UGB?", "Repetir");
                                return;
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                scan.IsScanning = false;
                                scan.IsAnalyzing = false;
                                infopage.BindingContext = info;
                                Navigation.InsertPageBefore(infopage, Navigation.NavigationStack[0]);
                                await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                scan.IsScanning = false;
                                scan.IsAnalyzing = false;
                                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Não foi possível carregar a sua carteirinha.", "Ok...");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Ops...", "Você não está conectado à internet.", "Ok!");
        }
        this.IsBusy = false;
    }

    public string GetImage(string foto)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(foto))
        {
            return "";
        }

        using (var WebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = WebClient.DownloadData("http://portal.ugb.edu.br/upload/ImagemAluno/" + foto);
            var sxtyfr = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            //var img = "data:image/jpg;base64," + sxtyfr;
            return sxtyfr;
        }
    }

    public static string sha256_hash(string value)
    {

        StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder(); using (SHA256 hash = SHA256Managed.Create())
        {

            Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;

            Byte[] result = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(value)); foreach (Byte b in result)

                Sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));

        }
        return Sb.ToString();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Upload the code you are using, also, didn't you change really anything? Have you tried to uninstall the application, do a clean and build of the project?

Comment: I've cleaned everything and VS is fully updated

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as code sample, usage pattern, etc

Comment: Do you have any updates for Zxing?

Comment: It is updated...

Comment: I posted my code up there

Comment: Try removing the obj and bin folders from every project. Then try running the project again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem... I just clean, build and rebuild the solution, then magic happens. Thank you all to help me.